# Flatten object without distorting it?

Tags: modeling

So I've been using Blender for a solid 20 minutes, I have no prior 3d modeling experience other than one time like 4 years ago i made a cringe worthy knife cause why not. Anyway I have a sword I'm making just for fun to learn blender and right now its like a giant pointy stick[image: This is my pointy stick sword thing]

now all i know currently is extruding, scale, and somewhat mirroring. Now my question is how would I flatten this to make it more... sword like without having to do some edward elric human transmutation ending up with some Atrocity.
[image: This is the Atrocity]
   But yes. I know I'm most likely using the wrong tool, and that's why I'm here ^-^. pls help me not make an alchemy Atrocity.

Comment: A useful tool you need to use is Insert Edge Loop, in Edit mode, click Ctrl+R, this will help you get a proper blade for the sword.

Comment: Scaling by a factor of -3243 was probably a little overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can either scale the whole sword in object mode by selecting it and pressing <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> to scale along the X axis or,

If you prefer a little more detail select your sword, go into edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, select only the faces corresponding to the blade part, and scale them along the X axis with <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd>.

If you go with the first option of scaling in object mode don't forget to apply the scale afterwards by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* when you're done.

**P.S.** Scaling (and other modal operators in Blende) use the cursor distance to the center for the screen at the moment of invoking the operator for precision factor, so make sure your mouse is not too close to the center when calling the command or you may end up with an overly sensitive scaling factor that may yield weird results as in your second image.